# Запуск глобальных модулей nodejs из кода

Tags: node.js, процесс

## Кратко

Почему не работает запуск глобального модуля как процесса из кода, если не указать расширение `cmd`, и как это исправить, не меняя запускающий код?

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp>node --version
v0.12.4

D:\Temp\Supertemp>phantomjs --version
1.9.8

D:\Temp\Supertemp>phantomjs.cmd --version
1.9.8

D:\Temp\Supertemp>node -e "var res=require('child_process').spawnSync('phantomjs',['--version']); console.log(res.stdout+'', res.error);"
null { [Error: spawnSync ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawnSync' }

D:\Temp\Supertemp>node -e "var res=require('child_process').spawnSync('phantomjs.cmd',['--version']); console.log(res.stdout+'', res.error);"
1.9.8
 undefined

D:\Temp\Supertemp>
```

## Подробно

Есть установленный глобально модуль, например, phantomjs

```
npm install -g phantomjs
```

Для его запуска как приложения предназначен файл

```
%appdata%\npm\phantomjs.cmd
```

В %path% соответствующий каталог присутствует, запуск из консоли в любой папке работает:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp>phantomjs
phantomjs> ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
^C
```

Проблема в том, что если делается попытка запустить соответствующий батник из кода на nodejs, то происходит ошибка:

```
{ '0':
   { [Error: spawn phantomjs ENOENT]
     code: 'ENOENT',
     errno: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'spawn phantomjs',
     path: 'phantomjs' } }
```

В прошлый раз сталкивался с этой проблемой в своём коде и решил её явным дописыванием расширения: запуск `phantomjs.cmd` работает корректно, а просто `phantomjs` - падает. Напоминаю, что просто из консоли работают оба варианта.

Сейчас столкнулся с той же проблемой, но на этот раз запуск делается установленным модулем (а именно, `html-inspector`).

Как можно решить проблему, не изменяя исходный код модуля?

---

PS: Задал [такой же вопрос на английском сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31478431/4928642), поскольку тут на него не отвечают.

Comment: А вы не пробовали использовать `exec` с `{shell: "cmd.exe"}`?

Comment: @avb, дело в том, что сейчас *установленный* модуль пытается сам запускать другой и у него это не получается. Я же не буду код этого модуля менять.

Comment: Первый результат в гугле по запросу "nodejs spawn enoent": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js Угадайте, почему вам не отвечают.

Comment: Также https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2318 как бы намекает, что авторам node.js покласть на переносимость. Есть вероятность, что это такая же придурь, как с руби — нормально работает только под линуксом.

Comment: @Discord, там ответ: "вот этот код поможет вам узнать, какой именно файл не существует", другой ответ: "проверьте, что всё существует". Как по-твоему оно связано с моим вопросом?

Comment: @Discord, а вот это (http://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2318) уже похоже на то, что надо

Comment: @Qwertiy По первой ссылке описан костыль с подменой функции. Можете нормально резолвить абсолютный путь там всеми доступными способами.